# Is there a way to exclude items inside of a for_each

Tags: terraform

I'm using a module to create a list of maps for me to iterate over:

```
module "regions" {
  source          = "hashicorp/subnets/cidr"
  base_cidr_block = "1.2.0.0/23"
  networks = [
    {
      name     = "in-use-us-east1"
      new_bits = 5
    },
    {
      name     = "in-use-us-west1"
      new_bits = 5
    },
    {
      name     = "in-use-us-west4"
      new_bits = 5
    },
    {
      name     = "in-use-us-central1"
      new_bits = 5
    },
    {
      name     = "not-in-use"
      new_bits = 1
    },
  ]
}
```

`module.regions` creates an object that looks like this:

```
  + regions         = {
      + base_cidr_block     = "1.2.0.0/23"
      + network_cidr_blocks = {
          + "not-in-use"                = "1.2.1.0/24"
          + "in-use-us-central1" = "1.2.0.32/28"
          + "in-use-us-east1"    = "1.2.0.48/28"
          + "in-use-us-west1"    = "1.2.0.0/28"
          + "in-use-us-west4"    = "1.2.0.16/28"
        }
      + networks            = [
          + {
              + cidr_block = "1.2.0.0/28"
              + name       = "in-use-us-west1"
              + new_bits   = 5
            },
          + {
              + cidr_block = "1.2.0.16/28"
              + name       = "in-use-us-west4"
              + new_bits   = 5
            },
          ... etc
```

I'm looping over the object like this:

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "regions" {
  for_each      = {for subnet in module.regions.networks:  subnet.name => subnet}
  provider      = google-beta
  name          = each.value.name
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = split("/", each.value.cidr_block)[1]
  address       = split("/", each.value.cidr_block)[0]
  project       = local.project_id
  network       = google_compute_subnetwork.my_vpc.network
}
```

All of this works great and does everything I want with one exception.

How do I exclude a key from the set?

I only want to loop over objects where `subnet.name` does not start with `not-in-use`.

Is this possible? I'm so close, I really don't want to have to reshape the whole thing in a new var in globals when I'm 90% of the way there. This is also very readable too.

I tried the following:
`for_each = {for subnet in module.regions.networks: subnet.name => subnet if regexall("^in-use", subnet.name)}`

But that throws an error:

```
Error: Invalid 'for' condition
The 'if' clause value is invalid: bool required.
```

I also tried wrapping `regexall()` in `length()` and that returned the same error.

## Edit

The right answer is `startswith()`, but FYI I just had to add `> 0` at the end of my if statement to make it work.

Also, I'm woefully behind on my tf version (0.14) so I have to stick with `regexall()` for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am somewhat hesitant to answer this because you almost completely did it yourself, but I will supply the final piece. While it is possible to do this with the `regex` function inside of a `can` function (it returns a `bool` whereas `regexall` returns a `list` which led to your error message since a `bool` is required for a conditional logical return), it would be even easier in your situation to use the [`startswith`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/startswith) function:

```
for_each = {for subnet in module.regions.networks: subnet.name => subnet if startswith(subnet.name, "in-use")}
```

Comment: I got regexall working by adding `> 0`- must have missed that in examples, but I didn't even know about `startswith` which is much more readable. For some reason my googling didn't turn this up.

Comment: Now I'm curious. My use of `split()` is pretty straight forward, but is there a function that supports reading cidrs and returning the network ID and mask? There are some cidr functions, but none for parsing prefixes like this I could find.

Comment: @red888 1. Yes `length(regexall(...)) > 0` would also return a `bool`, but it seemed like the least clean path forward of the three options, so i did not mention it. Also I meant `can(regex(...))` so editing answer for that. 2. I do not believe the TF "stdlib" of functions provides anything like that, and your usage of `split` is probably one of two options (the other being a `regex` and then accessing the matched element(s)).

Answer (score 1):

[The `hashicorp/subnets/cidr` module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/subnets/cidr) has its own convention for excluding some address ranges from the result, as described in [Changing Networks Later](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/subnets/cidr/latest#changing-networks-later):

> If an existing allocation becomes obsolute, you can set its name explicitly to `null` to skip allocating it a prefix but to retain the space it previously occupied in the address space.

In your case that would mean replacing `"not-in-use"` with `null`, like this:

```
module "regions" {
  source          = "hashicorp/subnets/cidr"
  base_cidr_block = "1.2.0.0/23"
  networks = [
    {
      name     = "us-east1"
      new_bits = 5
    },
    {
      name     = "us-west1"
      new_bits = 5
    },
    {
      name     = "us-west4"
      new_bits = 5
    },
    {
      name     = "us-central1"
      new_bits = 5
    },
    {
      name     = null
      new_bits = 1
    },
  ]
}
```

You are using the `networks` output instead of the `network_cidr_blocks` output, so some later text applies to your situation too:

> Because the `networks` output is a list that preserves the element indices of the requested networks, it *does* still include the skipped networks, but with their `name` and `cidr_blocks` attributes set to null.

The easiest way to avoid this complication would be to use `network_cidr_blocks` instead, like this:

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "regions" {
  provider = google-beta
  for_each = module.regions.network_cidr_blocks

  name          = each.key
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = split("/", each.value)[1]
  address       = split("/", each.value)[0]
  project       = local.project_id
  network       = google_compute_subnetwork.my_vpc.network
}
```

The `network_cidr_blocks` map automatically excludes any networks that have no name assigned.

If you *do* need to use `networks` for some reason then you'll need to filter the collection using an `if` clause in your `for` expression:

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "regions" {
  provider = google-beta
  for_each = {
    for subnet in module.regions.networks : subnet.name => subnet
    if subnet.name != null
  }

  name          = each.key
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = split("/", each.value.cidr_block)[1]
  address       = split("/", each.value.cidr_block)[0]
  project       = local.project_id
  network       = google_compute_subnetwork.my_vpc.network
}
```

Comment: This is the real answer to my question, but I asked a broader terraform code question. I'm doing it this way now. I'm sure I read this in the readme and just forgot the module had these features.